# apk with different certificate

Tags: android, ssl, key, publish

I'm facing a problem with the certificates, two weeks ago I made a backup of my pc, I save the project and the key.jks now in a different computer I'm trying to upgrade my app but It says this:

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>
> Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>
> [ SHA1: 90:F7:82:F9:C0:52:98:D7:EA:F9:9C:79:B9:00:1D:61:7E:5B:C5:06 ]
>
> and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>
> [ SHA1: 7B:67:D7:7B:C6:EB:53:49:94:41:86:89:C0:7A:2B:89:5B:0B:AC:A8 ]

Is there a way that I can fix this problem, the app has active users and I don't want to loose them

Comment: you have to sign the .apk with the same keystore file that you uploaded them , dont you have a copy of that ?

Comment: @DavidJhons I don't think so

Comment: then i donot think you can upgrade your app, but keep searching, sorry

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa I had the same problem There was a key that looked something like this > oi39.ElqNBBjc72BiKRprL9r4IpVKvtKxT-IioEpVlpW9FnoeKd8Do3jdoce93_komdho30cn_jd003j......Illsiiwk93si0s-D3g .... And I don't know where any other keystore file is saved. Is there a way I can search for the keystore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update your Apps, if you lost your APK Key. That is said also on Google's official Guide, to why it is soo important to save your API Keys.

You could try and contact Google Play service, but I doubt you'd get a positive respond or any respond at all. Best is to delete the App and re-create it and post it.

Otherwise, you can leave it there and you won't be able to update it without the original Key.

Here from official site [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Comment: I had the same problem There was a key that looked something like this > oi39.ElqNBBjc72BiKRprL9r4IpVKvtKxT-IioEpVlpW9FnoeKd8Do3jdoce‌​93_komdho30cn_jd003j‌​......Illsiiwk93si0s‌​-D3g .... I am hoping it's the apk key. If so how should I approach solving this problem?